# Why can't Vim replace || with &&?

Tags: vim

I have this line of code in line 12

```c
if(arr.length != 10 || arr.length != 20 || arr.length != 100)
```

I want to replace the `||` with `&&`, so I have this

```vim
12s/||/&&/g
```

But it vim just adds another set of `||` beside the current `||`s, how can this be fixed?

I already have `12s/||/&&/g`. I expected Vim to replace the `||` and `&&` but it seems like it's just adding to it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because vim usage questions should be asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: True enough....

Comment: When in doubt, escape with '\': `12s/||/\&\&/` probably works.

Comment: @JohnBayko Except your suggestion doesn't work....  with the range, that is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the '&'.

Just do a

```
:s/||/\&\&/g
```

Comment: Mine was first  ;-)

Comment: A bit of proper formatting would help, to.

Comment: Comedians everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the ampersand

```
:s/||/\&\&/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have explained the *how* but not the *why*. The solution - as already pointed out - is to escape the ampersand character as in

```vim
:12s/||/\&\&/g
```

This is necessary because Vim treats `&` in the replacement string in a special way as documented in [`:help s/\&`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s%2F%5C%26) (as this is a bit hard to find, it may be easier to read [`:help :substitute`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute) all the way down).

The `&` is a convenient shorthand for `\0` and will be replaced with the entire match. This is useful for a lot of things, e.g. to put every occurrence of "foo" in parentheses: `:%s/foo/(&)/g`.

So the command in the question will look for two pipe characters and replace them with the match, twice. So `||` is replaced by `||||` and it looks as if Vim had in fact appended to the original OR.